# ON BLUR IS NOT WORKING

Tags: validation

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter 
email" name="email" onblur="validation()">

<input type="text" name="war-email" id="war-email" value="" 
class="error"  readonly hidden/><br>

<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" 
placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" onblur="validation()">

<input type="text" name="war-pas" id="war-pas" value="" class="error"  
readonly hidden/><br>

<input type="cpassword" class="form-control" id="cpwd" 
placeholder="Enter password" name="cpwd" onblur="validation()">

<input type="text" name="war-cpas" id="war-cpas" value="" 
class="error"  readonly hidden/><br>

 <script>
        function validation(){
        if(document.getElementById("email").value==""){
        $("#war-email").show();
        document.getElementById("war-email").value="this is invalid email";
        document.getElementById("war-email").style.color="red";
         }else{
        document.getElementById("war-email").value="this is valid email";
        document.getElementById("war-email").style.color="green";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("pwd").value==""){
        $("#war-pas").show();
        document.getElementById("war-pass").value="Short password";
        document.getElementById("war-pas").style.color="red";
        }else{
        document.getElementById("war-pas").value="Strong password";
        document.getElementById("war-pas").style.color="green";
        }
        var len=document.getElementById("cpwd").value;  
        if(document.getElementById("pwd").value!=
        document.getElementById("cpwd").value==)         
        {
        $("#war-cpas").show();
        document.getElementById("war-cpass").value="Both password should 
        matched";
        document.getElementById("war-cpas").style.color="red";
        }else{
        document.getElementById("war-cpas").value="matched..!!";
        document.getElementById("war-cpas").style.color="green";
        }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see here [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also please explain what's the problem more than just "onblur is not working". What should it do? What does it do now?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your code in a snippet so it will be easier for us to understand. Anyway, I'll tell how to attach `blur` event using jQuery.

```js
$("input#name").on("blur", function()
{
  if(!this.value)
  {
    alert("Please fill out the name");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <label>Your Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</form>
```

If you need any other help, just let me know :-)